# How to restrict access of a function to storage account in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network

I have two functions in a function app and each function have a blob trigger that monitors same blob in a container. How to restrict access of one of the functions and let another one continue monitoring the blob in container?

Comment: Why not delete the one not needed ?

Comment: if they're not allowed to see the other's blob, put them in separate function apps and use a KeyVault for each to stop them reading each others' blob